# Wait for Node.connect before using :global.whereis_name

Tags: erlang, elixir

I have the following function:

```
  def join(id) do
    if Node.connect(:"#{id}@127.0.0.1") do
      send :global.whereis_name(id), {:join, id}
    end
  end
```

I receive the error:

```
(ArgumentError) argument error
               :erlang.send(:undefined, ...
```

which I assume is because `Node.connect` does some gathering of information and when I call `:global.whereis_name` it has not finished yet. If I throw in a `:timer.sleep(1000)` sure enough I don't get an error. Is there a more elegant solution? I would like repeat `:global.whereis_name` until successful or a timeout is reached.

EDIT:

I should mention that I already have a node registered with the name `id`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could do a `:global.sync()` before `:global.whereis_name(id)`